# Keplerian Elements for the Moon and Earth around their Barycenter

Tags: the-moon, earth, natural-satellites, kepler, earths-orbit

So I'm looking to replicate the inner Solar System to a decent degree of accuracy. So far I've been utilizing the Keplerian Elements and Equations for the planets, as shown [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/aprx_pos_planets.pdf). There is one issue with this though:

For the Earth and Moon, I only get the path of the Barycenter. This is great, but it means that the next thing I need is the Earth's and Moon's Keplerian Elements relative to their Barycenter. Now I can get the starting element values from [JPL HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi#top) or the [JPL Planetary Satellite Mean Orbital Parameters](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?sat_elem#legend). However, I get a bit stuck on what the best way to evolve these values over time is.

I'm thinking that maybe the answer lies in utilizing the Longitude Rate (*n*) in the [JPL Planetary Satellite Mean Orbital Parameters](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?sat_elem#legend) for approximate motion.

**Does anyone have any solid resources I could utilize to determine a good solution to this problem (i.e. books/links)?**

*Also, just so I know, does a question like this actually belong here? Or is it more appropriate for [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/)?*

Comment: I believe this question is on topic.

Comment: @MikeG Thanks by the way! Still looking for an answer unfortunately :(

Comment: Take a look at https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36713/where-can-i-get-j2000-epoch-initial-mean-longitudes-for-all-planets-and-celestia and look in Appendix C.1